# WooCommerce Local Pickup plus force shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m using [WooCommerce Local Pickup Plus](https://woo.com/document/local-pickup-plus/) plugin, along with another plugin for exporting orders. I would like to ensure that when a customer chooses local pickup, the shipping address on the order reflects the address of the pickup point.

Here’s where I currently stand:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', function($order){
    $local_shipping = false;
    foreach($order->get_shipping_methods() as $method){
        if($method->get_method_id() === 'local_pickup_plus'){
            $local_shipping = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($local_shipping){
        // all of the local pickup address info
        $order->set_shipping_country('FR');
        $order->set_shipping_address_1($address_1);
        $order->set_shipping_address_2($address_2);  
        $order->set_shipping_postcode($postcode);
        $order->set_shipping_city($city);
    }
});
```

When I use this code, I no longer have a delivery address on my test order. So, I know that I’m affecting what I want, but no variable is being returned. I think the variables are not correct, but I’m having difficulty finding the right ones.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Does anyone have some insight?

Comment: That is normal as the variables `$address_1`, `$address_2`, `$postcode`, and `$city` are not defined in your code, so you get an empty shipping address… You should avoid to set as customer shipping address the selected pickup location. Try to find the pickup location in `$order->get_items('shipping')` as custom order item metadata (or maybe as custom order metadata)...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe I don't really have a choice but to proceed this way. I export the order to a software and use the WooCommerce fields such as "shipping_address_1," "shipping_city," etc. The software requires the shipping information to be in these fields because I cannot change the field used based on the delivery method. I will try to use the meta, but the first thing I notice is that the address is not separated into city, address, and ZIP code.